# Relation between convolution and $L^p$ norms

Tags: lp-spaces, convolution, holder-inequality

I have to prove that for any $g \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and for any function $u(t)$ bounded and continuous, the following inequality holds:

$$sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}}|(g \ast u)(t)| \leqslant ||g||_1\cdot||u||_\infty$$

I guess that the starting point is the Holder's inequality, which states that:

$$\bigl| \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g(t)\overline{u(t)}dt \bigr| \leqslant ||g||_1\cdot||u||_\infty$$

Then, it is sufficient to prove that:

$$sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}}|(g \ast u)(t)|  \leqslant \bigl| \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g(t)\overline{u(t)}dt \bigr|  $$

However I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, let $v_x(t) = \overline{u(x-t)}$.  Then $(g * u)(x) = \int g(t) v_x(t) dt$, and note that $||v_x||_{\infty} = ||u||_{\infty}$.

Comment: But can I take vx(t) out of the integral if the variable wrt I am integrating is x?

Comment: Your notation is inconsistent between the first and second lines.  On the first line you use t where I use x, but in the second line you integrated with respect to t, which is what I am assuming in my comment.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of Holder's inequality you wrote above is not the full power of the inequality.  We really have the inequalities

$$
| \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} g(t) \overline{u(t)} dt | \leq  \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} |g(t) \overline{u(t)} | dt = \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} |g(t) {u(t)} | dt \leq ||g||_1 ||u||_{\infty}
$$

(where the second inequality is really Holder's inequality).  Now, for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, let $v_x(t) = u(x - t)$.  Then observe that $||v_x||_{\infty} = ||\overline{v_x}||_{\infty} = ||u||_{\infty}$.  It follows that

$$
| (g \ast u)(x)| = 
| \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} g(t) v_x(t) dt | \leq \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} |g(t) v_x(t) | dt = \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} |g(t) \overline{v_x(t)} | dt \leq ||g||_1 ||u||_{\infty}
$$

Then taking the supremum preserves the inequalities.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I see what you meant. You have been really clear!

The problem is that in the notes I am using, the Holder's inequality is just stated without the absolute value inside the integral, so I was missing that step. Are you sure that moving the absolute value inside, still the inequality holds?

Comment: Yes I am.  Holder's inequality is really an inequality of norms, and the L^1 norm uses absolute value of the integrand.

Comment: Now that I read it again, I noticed that you call vx(t)=u(x−t), but isn't it vt(x)=u(x-t)? Does it make any difference? 

Because in the note I have the following definition for the right shift operator:
(Sxf)(t) = f(t-x).

With this definition the integral inside has one function of t and one function of t. 

I guess it is the same because you can see one as right shift and another as left shift, but since the scalar is real you can take a negative one and they are the same. Is it true?

Comment: By definition, $(g \ast u)(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(t) u (x - t) dt$.  The integral in this case is with respect to t, and so when we fix any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we can view $u(x - t)$ as a function of t which is dependent upon our parameter x.  Hence I use the notation $v_x(t)$.